# d3 vary line/area color along x-axis in line graph

Tags: graph, d3.js, line, gradient

I'm trying to vary the color along a line graph (and the area under it). I've seen a lot of examples using gradients to vary the color, the in all those examples the color is varied along the y-axis. I'm wanting to vary along the x-axis according to time periods (so 8am-noon would be one color, noon-5pm another, etc.).

Is there a way to modify gradients to do this or some other relatively simple way? I'm basing my code off of this example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), just with the time periods changed to minutes instead of days. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradients to modify along the x axis as well. The only thing that you need to do differently is to set the x1, x2, y1, y2 accordingly. See e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) for an example. The stops you set for the gradient would need to correspond to the time periods.

For a complete example that uses gradients to vary the colour along the x axis, check out [this](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and examples. I figured it should be possible with gradients, but for some reason I couldn't find any mention of it.